# c# wpf import javascript function from .js file

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf

I am working on C# WPF project and i want to include .js file function in my User Control file of wpf application 
I am not able to get any solution,can anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Edge.js to script Node.js code inside of a C# application: http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2014/05/script-nodejs-from-net-using-edgejs.html